# How many strings of length $7$ contain the substring bcd?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Suppose there is a string of length $7$ that contain letters from $\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g\}$ without repetition. How many combinations can be made so that there is a substring "bcd" (b,c,d are consecutive and adjacent) in each?

I am quite confident that there are 7! possible combinations of all the letters, but other than that I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Try to think of an algorithm for constructing such a string. Then, compute how many ways one could execute each step of the algorithm. Finally, sum or multiply the numbers together using counting rules.

Comment: Think of bcd as a block

Answer (score 0):

Consider 'bcd' to be a block or a single element. Then, your question becomes equivalent to finding the number of permutations of {bcd,a,e,f,g}.
Then your answer is 5!.